# My 1980s telecaster neck pickup is louder then usual but the bridge pickup is almost silent even turned all the way up

Tags: electric-guitar, pick-ups, repair, bridge, guitar-neck

My 80s telecasters neck pickup is almost 2x louder then before and the bridge pickup is huming but makes vary little sound when turned all the way up any help

Comment: You're going to have to get inside & see if you can see anything wrong with the wiring, for starters. After that, do you have a multimeter?

Comment: Open up, and check for dry joints - which will cause both symptoms.

Comment: Or take it to a repair tech and let them fix it for you.